# How to show a "please wait" message to a user after form submits in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'd like to show a "please wait" message to the user after hitting "submit" on a form. For now I've managed to at least disable the button after the user clicks it, but how can I display a "please wait" message / modal while the next page loads?

This is my code:

```
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-md" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Next">
```

```
$('form').submit(function(){
   $(this).children('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
 });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61305024/success-message-display-on-submit-html-form

Comment: You could [create and append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append#appending_an_element_and_text) an element (or [reveal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#display_value_comparison) an existing one) that contains "please wait" text. You could even style it to look like a modal or dialogue box. I encourage you to give it a try and, if you get stuck, let us know what specifically goes wrong.

Comment: @MisterJojo : it's entirely possible.  you show the indicator just prior to submitting the form and hide it on document ready...

Comment: Maybe rename the submit button value? `$(this).children('input[type=submit]').attr('value', 'Please wait...');`

Comment: It depends on how the form is being submitted.  Real form `submit` actions trigger a page refresh by default; you could stop that by using `preventDefault()` but then the user would never see the results of the form.  Browsers don't typically wait until the form submit has fully returned before clearing the page, so just changing the text as some are suggesting won't be reliable. Many forms are handled via XHR these days instead of as form submits; suggestions like @showdev and @devlincarnate's comments above would work if you were doing an async background call instead of a form submit.

Comment: @DanielBeck It appears that the OP wants to show the message "while the next page loads," so it didn't seem necessary to me to prevent the submit action or submit via XHR. But of course I could be wrong; perhaps the OP might help clarify.

Comment: exactly my point, @showdev: there isn't a (reliable) way to show a message "while the next page loads" other than by submitting via XHR and waiting for the promise to resolve, because browsers don't necessarily wait for the next page to load before clearing the current one.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much everyone for all the options! @Jack, I love the idea of simply changing the button text to "Please wait..." - super simple and elegant.

Comment: @DanielBeck I think you mean the page could go blank before the wait for the next page to load. I suppose that's true. In my experience with slow connections, the page most often stays the same until something useful is received back, which can take a few seconds or more. I'd consider a "please wait" message like this to be an optimization of user experience, even if it's not completely reliable.

Comment: @DanielBeck, no need to prevent the default - I want the form to be submitted, it just takes forever for the next page to load.

Comment: @showdev, fair point, you convinced me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this answer, I have provided a hidden `<div>` with the "Please Wait" text. This could be any HTML in any style you want. When the button is clicked, the wait message is displayed and the submit button is disabled. Since this does not wait for the UI changes to happen, it is possible that the form will submit before the user sees the Please Wait message.

```js
$('form').submit(function(){
  $('#waiting').show();
  $(this).children('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <div>Please submit the form</div>
  <input class="btn btn-primary btn-md" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Next">
</form>
<div id="waiting" style="display:none">Please wait...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `div` styled with `display: none;` and then you show it while triggering the submission.

```html
<div style="display: none;" id="please_wait" class="text-center">
    <p>Please Wait...</p>
</div>
```

```js
$('form').submit(function (e) { 
    $(this).children('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#please_wait').show();
});
```